# How to take a hash of key/val pairs and set ActiveRecord attributes with it

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby hash that I'm retrieving via a remote web API. I have an ActiveRecord model that has the same attributes as the keys in the hash. Is there a trivial way with Ruby on Rails 4 to assign the key/val pairs from the hash to the model instance? Is it possible to ignore the keys that do not exist?

Answer (score 5):

Super-easy!

Update the attributes without saving:

```
model.attributes = your_hash
# in spite of resembling an assignemnt, it just sets the given attributes
```

Update attributes saving:

```
model.update_attributes(your_hash)
# if it fails because of validation, the attributes are update in your object
# but not in the database
```

Update attributes, save, and raise if unable to save

```
model.update_attributes!(your_hash)
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update):

*update(attributes)*

*Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the record, all wrapped in a transaction. If the object is invalid, the saving will fail and false will be returned.*

So try

`model.update(dat_hash) #dat_hash being the hash with the attributes`

I have been doing the same thing in Rails 3.2 using update_attributes, which is the same thing. Here is my code:

```
def update
  @form = get_form(params[:id])
  @form.update_attributes(params[:form])
  @form.save
  if @form.save
    render json: @form
  else
    render json: @form.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

It only updates the attributes that are in the hash.